# css won't load in Blazor running on Azure app service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm deploying a Blazor app to an Azure app service.  The build and deployment on Azure pipelines works fine and the site runs.

I started with a package deployment but the site wouldn't start.  Error said it couldn't find the startup dll.  I switched to a zip deployment.  Now the site starts but won't load the css.

[image]

The folder structure is odd but I guess normal for app service.  Its site > wwwroot (all the dll's are here) > wwwroot (site.styles.css is here) > css (rest of the css files).

[image]

Here is my yaml file.

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Development'
  project: '"$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/HR Taxonomy Change Management/HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj"'

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    
  steps:

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: "HR Taxonomy Change Management/*.csproj"
      feedsToUse: 'config'
      nugetConfigPath: nuget.config

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: "HR Taxonomy Change Management/HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj"
      arguments: '--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'  

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: "HR Taxonomy Change Management/HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj"
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/artifact"'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/artifact'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: 'ls $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/publishedApp'
      workingDirectory: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Deploy to Azure'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'HR Data Governance(2442165c-339d-4e83-a443-a6583c372938)'
      appType: 'webAppLinux'
      appName: 'hrchangemanagement'
      resourceGroupName: 'HRChangeManagement'
      deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
      startUpCommand: 'dotnet "HR Taxonomy Change Management.dll"'
      package: ' $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/publishedApp/*.zip'
```

Any suggestions you can offer are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error code occurred because your Web app could not find your css files after deploying the Blazor web app. Make sure the css files are present inside wwwroot folder and recheck the code in your css file like below:-

***css files inside wwwroot/wwwroot folder:-***

[image]

***Other Files deployed successfully inside wwwroot folder like below:-***

[image]

[image]

**My Azure repository**, **Make sure all the css files are in the correct folder** like below:-

[image]

*My Azure pipelines to deploy above app:-*

**My YAML pipeline script:-**

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'subscription(xxxx-xxx-44d6-b4fd-exxx)'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'siliconwebapp098'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

**Output:-**

*Deployment successful:-*

[image]

**Blazor app is running successfully like below:-**

[image]

One way to resolve your issue is to check the **Diagnose and Solve Problems** and **get insights** on your error:-

[image]

**Check Log stream** and get insight on your error code like below:-

[image]

Comment: I have checked and everything on the pipeline side looks good.